# Compare Rows to only send specific rows in Informatica

Tags: sql, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I needed guidance on how to solve for below in informatica powercenter.

My source flat file.

|Student|Subject|PF|

|1|Science|Fail|

|1|Maths|Pass|

|2|Science|Fail|

I need to apply logic where if a particular student has two rows in source like for student 1 in the table and has "pass" in either one subject then I need to send both rows forward but if a particular student only has 1 row like for student 2 in the table and row has "fail" then I don't want to pass that row forward.

I am not sure how to implement above logic.

Answer (score 0):

We can use self join to count how many records have `Pass` for a student. If count is >0, all records will be passed to next transformation.
You can do this by following below steps -

1. First use a sorter - Order by key Student.
2. Use an aggregator, create a new column like below. Please mention column Student as group by key.

```
count_pass = COUNT(* , PF='Pass')
```

3. Use a joiner to join aggregator data and original data. Join will be normal join and on Student column. Bring count_pass from aggregator.
4. Then add a filter with below condition -

```
count_pass >0
```

Whole mapping look like -

```
SQ --> SRT --> AGG-->\
          \----------> JNR--> FIL-->TGT
```

Comment: This worked Thank You